# Cast to ObjectID failed - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I am trying to add an event to a users profile once they click on the event.  I am getting the following error - Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ event: '600066640807165d042b91dd' }" at path "event".  The route for creating a profile and for creating an event work as expected.  The 600 is the id of an event that I created and I am now trying to push that event into the users profile but it is not working.

Here is my code

Profile Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    event: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'event'
        }
    ],
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    company: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Event Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timeOfEvent: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    dateOfEvent: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    speaker: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
            },
        bio: {
            type: String,
            required: true
            },
        interests: {
            type: String,
            required: true
            }
        },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

module.exports = Event = mongoose.model('event', EventSchema);
```

Route

```
// @route   PUT api/profile/me/addEvent
// @desc    PUT current users profile
// @access  Private

router.put('/me/addEvent', auth, async (req, res) => {

    const event = req.body;
    
    const profileFields = {};
    if(event) profileFields.event = event;

    try {

        let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

        if(profile) {
            profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate( { user: req.user.id }, { $push: {"event": event}}, { new: true });
            
            res.status(201).send(profile);
        }
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error'); 
    }

});
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: if your problem is not solved, leave a comment, if my answer is true accept it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass an object id to event, the `req.body` is a object for get objectId of event do like this

```
let {event} = req.body
profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate( { user: req.user.id }, { $push: {"event": event}}, { new: true });
```

Comment: when I do this i get this output Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the push method and save it

```js
 if(profile) {
            profile.event.push(/*Event ID*/);  
            await profile.save();
            res.status(201).send(profile);
        }
```